# Modify library class at runtime - java/maven

Tags: java, maven, byte-buddy

I'm working on a Maven Plugin and I need to modify one class of an external jar (used during maven execution), to add:

- a new field on this class
- a getter for the field
- some behavior to an existing setter to populate the field

The library code should use my 'new' class, and I want to be able to use the getter to retrieve some additional information.

Instances of this class are created *within* the library code (I'm not creating them in my code, I just need to access them). 
Class is a non-final public class.

Do you know if this feasible and which is the best way to do it? Is it possible to do it with ByteBuddy?

EDIT: I cannot wrap the class, because it's not instantiated in my own code, let me elaborate a bit.

There's a library class named "Parser" that instantiate and populate some "Element" instances. My code looks like:

```
List<library.Element> elements = new library.Parser(file).parse();
```

the Parser.parse() method calls "Element.setProperties(List properties)" on each element.
I want to be able to enrich the setProperties method to store the original list of properties (that are lost otherwise)

Thanks
Giulio

Comment: Where are instances of the class created? Outside the library and used as input or? Is the class final?

Comment: edited the question based on your questions.

Comment: Why do you need to modify a class of an external jar? Why not writing a simple wrapper class and change it accordingly and use the jar with the wrapper class instead of writing a whole maven plugin?

Comment: Perhaps fork the dependency, rewrite the class as needed and provide a shaded version  in your own jar?

Comment: I've further clarified the question. 
I would prefer not to fork the dependency because it's just a small change on only one class

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm writing a Maven plugin to do some validations of a file before code generation. I need to slightly modify the parsing of this file (done in external library) to retain additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I managed to obtain the wanted result with byte-buddy (I don't know if it's the best solution but it works):

1. instrument library class (library.Element) using 'rebase' strategy to delegate the method 'setProperties' call to an interceptor.

**Note**: this must be done as the first instruction of the maven plugin execution when library.Element.class is not yet loaded (I didn't want to use a JVM agent)

2. define the above interceptor as a class that stores the original 'properties' value in a global map (key = identity hash code of the object, value = properties) and then call the original 'setProperties' method of library.Element
3. change my code to get properties from the map, instead of library.Element getter (I had already a wrapper of this class).

If someone is interested, I can show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion sounds a bit hackish, and in general what you want to do would not even be possible without generating sources from the JAR, modifying them, and then repackaging.  If I faced this problem, I would consider using a decorator pattern instead.  You can create a wrapper which exposes all the methods of your JAR, except it would add one extra field along with a getter and setter.

```
import com.giulio.old.jar.everything.*;

public class WrapperOfJar {
    private String newField;

    public String getNewField() { // ... }
    public void setNewField() { // ... }

    // all getters and setters from current JAR
}
```

Now your users will see the same interface, plus one new method for your field.  This answer assumes that the class in question is not `final`.